# Construction of a point C with compass and ruler so that P is the centre of the circumcircle of △ABC.

Tags: geometry

Let three points A, B, P ∈ E2 be given in general position.
Construction of a point C with compass and ruler so that P is the centre of the circumcircle of △ABC.
I am not quite sure how to do that. I've tried different approaches, but I'm not really getting anywhere.

Comment: if $P$ is not at the perpendicular bissector of $AB$, it is impossible; if it is, then draw the circle $\odot(P,PA)$ and take any point on it that is not $A$ nor $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Use this fact that perpendicular bisector of AB meets the bisector of angle ACB on circumcircle. So the necessary condition is that P must be on perpendicular bisector of AB. In this case draw a circle center at P( D in figure) passing points A and B. As shown in figure any point on arc AB except A and B can be C.